# Style changes in Vuetify 3 DataTables

Tags: css, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have a question about the Vuetify3 DataTables:

The icons and checkboxes are transparent, I can't change the property of this and i wish to change the headers of title with other color.

Someone can help me to resolve this?

Here is my code:

```
         <v-data-table
           v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
              :headers="donner.headers"
              :items="donner.content"
              item-key="name"
              class="blue-header"
              show-select
           >
         </v-data-table> 

         <style>
          .blue-header th {
           background-color: blue;
           };
         </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial header background color is set by this declaration:

```css
.v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > td,
.v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr th,
.v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table tbody > tr > td,
.v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table tbody > tr th {
  background: rgb(var(--v-theme-surface));
}
```

These selectors give a high [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), that you need to match in your declaration.

Your `blue-header` class lands on the element with the `v-data-table` class, so this should do it:

```css
.v-data-table.blue-header .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr th,
.v-data-table.blue-header .v-table__wrapper > table tbody > tr th {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Alternatively, you can pull out the crowbar and do `background-color: blue !important;`, but it is not really necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

- Icons Resolves:
  I just forget to install the icons on my project.
  So it's done now

" npm install @mdi/font -D "

- Now my problem is to change the background of headers.

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify 3 DataTables can be styled using CSS. Here are some examples of how to change the style of a Vuetify 3 DataTable:

1. Change the background color of the table:

   /* Change the background color of the table */
   .v-datatable {
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   }
2. Change the font size and font family of the table:
   /* Change the font size and font family of the table */

   .v-datatable {
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   }
3. Change the border color and width of the table:
   /* Change the border color and width of the table */
   .

   v-datatable {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;   /* Border width */   border-color: #ccc;   /* Border color */ }